# stateProvider not loading the correct controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I am building an angular app using MEAN.js with 2 type of objects :

- I want to access the first type with urls like : /objectType1/:param1
- And the second with urls like : /objectType1/:param1/objectType2/:param2

---

I have created the 2 modules corresponding to the 2 object types.

The first work well but not the second.

in the second module I have a file named objectType2.routes.js :

```
'use strict';

// Setting up route
angular.module('objectType2').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider.
        state('viewObjectType2', {
            url: '/objectType1/:param1/objectType2/:param2',
            templateUrl: 'modules/objectType2/views/view-objectType2.client.view.html',
            controller: 'objectType2Controller'
        });
    }
]);
```

My problem is the controller used is objectType1Controller from the objectType1 module, despite me explicitly stating

```
controller: 'objectType2Controller'
```

However, the correct template is called.

What could I be missing?

Edit:
In the module objectType1, the file named objectType1.routes.js :

```
'use strict';

// Setting up route
angular.module('objectType1').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider.
        state('viewObjectType1', {
            url: '/objectType1/:param1',
            templateUrl: 'modules/objectType1/views/view-objectType1.client.view.html',
            controller: 'objectType1Controller'
        });
    }
]);
```

Comment: Did you try to add a console.log('objectType2Controller') and console.log('objectType2Controller') into each controller and see what the console say ?

Comment: Yes exactly, thats how i made sure the objectType2Controller is not used unless i delete the objectType1Controller

Comment: Could you add the state for viewObjectType1 ?

Comment: edit : Added the route.js for the module 1

Comment: How you are using the two modules in layout/template ?

Comment: To answer Swapnesh, in my controller objectType2Controller :


`$scope.findOne = function() {
   $scope. = ObjectType2.get({ param1: $stateParams.param1, param2 : $stateParams.param2 });
};`
  
 
Where ObjectType2 is a ngRessource object